# Placing Google Analytics in a separate file

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, head

I have a bunch of static webpages that used to have GA code placed before `</body>` tag. I was tasked to place them before the `</head>` tag (as recommended by [Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en)). (Personally, I think this is a silly request but you have to make the client happy.)

Now, my question is not about the benefit of having GA code in the `<body>` opposed to the `<head>` but about whether placing the GA code in a script file (that is in the `<head>` tag) would be the same as placing it inline right before `</head>` tag?

For example,

**index.html**

```
 <head>
     <!-- some stylesheet files -->
     <!-- some script files -->
     <script>
         // Google Analytics code
     </script>
 </head>
```

versus

**index.html**

```
 <head>
     <!-- some stylesheet files -->
     <!-- some script files -->
     <script src="main.js"></script>
     <!-- some more script files -->
 </head>
```

**main.js**

```
 // random JS code followed by Google Analytics code
```

Comment: Yes, exactly the same. What you would like to achieve exactly ?

Comment: To not have to explicitly place the GA code on all pages. Since all pages share the same JS file e.g. `main.js`, I was thinking of just putting the GA code there instead of having to place the inline GA code before all the `</head>` tags.

Comment: Got you! Please check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place the GA code inside your **main.js** then you'll not have to explicitly place the GA code on all pages.